# Cannot compare &u8 with u8

Tags: vector, lambda, split, rust, borrowing

```
fn count_spaces(text: Vec<u8>) -> usize {
    text.split(|c| c == 32u8).count()
}
```

The above function does not compile, and gives the following error on the comparison:

> trait `&u8: std::cmp::PartialEq` not satisfied

I read this as: "`c` is a borrowed byte and cannot be compared to a regular byte", but I must be reading this wrong.

What would be the appropriate way to split a `Vec<u8>` on specific values?

I do realize that there are options when reading files, like splitting a `BufReader` or I could convert the vector to a string and use `str::split`. I might go with such a solution (passing in a `BufReader` instead of a `Vec<u8>`), but right now I'm just playing around, testing stuff and want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The code

You are actually reading it right: `c` is indeed a borrowed byte and cannot be compared to a regular byte. Try using any of the functions below instead:

```
fn count_spaces(text: Vec<u8>) -> usize {
    text.split(|&c| c == 32u8).count()
}

fn count_spaces(text: Vec<u8>) -> usize {
    text.split(|c| *c == 32u8).count()
}
```

The first one uses pattern matching on the parameter (`&c`) to dereference it, while the second one uses the dereference operator (`*`).

#### Why is `c` a `&u8` instead of a `u8`?

If you take a look at the [split](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split) method on the docs, you will see that the closure parameter is a *borrow* of the data in `Vec`. In this case, it means that the parameter will be `&u8` instead of `u8` (so in your code you are actually comparing `&u8` to `u8`, which Rust doesn't like).

In order to understand why the closure takes the parameter by borrow and not by value, consider what would happen if the parameter was taken by value. In the case of `Vec<u8>`, there would be no problem since `u8` implements `Copy`. However, in the case of a a `Vec<String>`, each `String` would be moved into the closure and destroyed!

Comment: Thanks!

Was trying to find a way to dereference it, but there was no mention of it in the References and Borrowing chapter of the Rust Book. Should have been able to guess it was the same operator as in C. It's been almost a year since I last did any Rust, but have been wanting to get back into it, so I'm a bit rusty on the syntax (pardon the pun). :/

I really like the first version where the dereferencing happens early.

Comment: It is great to see you coming back to Rust! Don't hesitate to hang out on the [rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust) or #rust at irc.mozilla.org in case you want to follow the community more closely.